# How to maintain ImageView Zoomable while adding On Touch Listener

Tags: kotlin

Right now I'm using Image Zoom library using https://github.com/Baseflow/PhotoView

which works great for the zoom I want. But I also want to add click Left, Right and Middle function on the Image so I add this code

The ImageView is on adapter so my code look like this:

```
bukuAdapter?.setOnTouchPhotoItem { item, event, width ->

    val curPos = (bukuLayoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    var nextPos = 0
 

    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
     
            startX = event.x
            Log.e("HK","startX=" + startX)
            true
        }
        MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
     
            val halfWidth = width / 2
            val isClickOnLeftSide = event.x < halfWidth - threshold
            val isClickOnRightSide = event.x > halfWidth + threshold

     
            if (isClickOnLeftSide) {
            
                Log.e("HK","Left is Clicked")
                 
            } else if (isClickOnRightSide) {
            
                Log.e("HK","Right is Clicked") 
 
            } else {
                Log.e("HK","Middle is Clicked") 
            }

            true
        }
        else -> false
    }
}
```

while above code works perfectly, for some reason the zoom effect is now not working. is there a way to retain the zoom and custom click at the same time?